# Git. How to add all files that are not those returning error?

Tags: linux, git, filesystems

Using linux, I would like to do something like in the script below using git:

```
cd /
sudo git init .
sudo git add -A
sudo git commit -m "Genesis."
```

I would like to do this to see which files are changed in the filesystem when I install some software and for another purposes of mine.

But when I try `sudo git add -A` I receive some error messages like:

```
error: readlink("proc/10/exe"): No such file or directory
error: unable to index file proc/10/exe
fatal: adding files failed
```

But this is OK, probably /proc files will not help me so much.
So I would simple add all files but ignoring the files that I receive errors.
I tried `sudo git add -A --ignore-errors` and a bigger output had come, unfortunately when running `git status` nothing happened.

So, how could I add all files that will not cause errors to achieve what I need?

Comment: Well... I think storing a whole root in git is not a good idea. At least because your `.git` will bloat very fast. Maybe zfs/nilfs with lightweight snapshiotting is a better alternative

Comment: @vsminkov This would be for inspection and test purposes. .git will grow fast but this would be not a problem to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying several things looks like I'd reached an answer:

```
sudo find * -type f | sudo xargs git add
```

This operation took a long time but worked.
The truth is I ran `sudo find {folder here} -type f | sudo xargs git add` to each folder in `/`.

I was trying to do this on a vagrant VM (ubuntu/trusty64) and after the operation the .git folder was with about 600MB.

Then I searched for a command to get all files that was not tracked and add them to .gitignore.

So I used this:

```
sudo git status -s | grep -e "^\?\?" | grep -v ".gitignore" | cut -c 4- >> .gitignore
```

Unfortunately 7 pem "files" was not put in the .gitignore:

```
    "etc/ssl/certs/AC_Ra\303\255z_Certic\303\241mara_S.A..pem"
    "etc/ssl/certs/Certinomis_-_Autorit\303\251_Racine.pem"
    "etc/ssl/certs/EBG_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sa\304\237lay\304\261c\304\261s\304\261.pem"
    "etc/ssl/certs/NetLock_Arany_=Class_Gold=_F\305\221tan\303\272s\303\255tv\303\241ny.pem"
    "etc/ssl/certs/T\303\234B\304\260TAK_UEKAE_K\303\266k_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sa\304\237lay\304\261c\304\261s\304\261_-_S\303\274r\303\274m_3.pem"
    "etc/ssl/certs/T\303\234RKTRUST_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sa\304\237lay\304\261c\304\261s\304\261_H5.pem"
    "etc/ssl/certs/T\303\234RKTRUST_Elektronik_Sertifika_Hizmet_Sa\304\237lay\304\261c\304\261s\304\261_H6.pem"
```

I tried put them manually but didn't work. But I think, for inspection purposes, this will not be a problem.

If is there a way to put this files in .gitignore I would like to know.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a **.gitignore** file in your directory and add the names of the files that you want to ignore.

Steps:
 1. vi .gitignore
 2. add "proc/10/exe" to the file.
 3. Press ESC key and :wq!
 4. Now try to add again. - it should work.

Comment: Unfortunally this solution will not work very well to me becase even when I ignore all /proc in .gitignore I receive a huge list of errors. I need a solution that can handle the errors automatically.